# HowTo for starting with Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, project, aptana3

I apologize in advance if this has been asked and answered before. I was earching for some help but didn't find anything appropriate. 
While there are sufficient HowTos for starting programming with Aptana Studio (AS), I didn't find any that helps moving a project from another IDE to AS. There are some specialties:

My project is entirely in PHP.
I have all the files of the project stored locally in a folder which is the base folder of the local web server, so I can check programming results locally before uploading them.
However, AS must also upload changed files to the server which is accessible publicly.

When I start a project in AS, I am told that the folder which contains my project contains files (logically), and I am not allowed to use this location. So would I have to start with an empty folder and then copy the files into that folder? Seems dumb to me. Besides, then I would have to copy files to two different servers: the local one for testing and the public one for release. Would that be supported by AS?

Is there a HowTo for this kind of scenario? Or can someone kindly explain how to go about it to get started with AS? I may be blind for the obvious, somethimes conceptual approaches are different to how my mind works, but it's pretty adjustable once I know how it works.

I can't use my previous IDE any longer, it's been abandoned for a long time by the programmer and misses more and more needed functions, and it doesn't work anymore under current OSs.

Comment: If you're changing IDEs because your previous one has been abandoned why are you switching to Aptana which is also functionally abandoned? Aptana was never much more than a fork of Eclipse, and Eclipse/PDT is still alive. On the other hand there's PHPstorm which people actually seem to _like_, as well as Atom, VScode, and more. That said, StackOverflow is not a forum to solicit opinions or software recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I wasn't aware that AptanaStudio has been abandoned, but now that you mention it... The last update seems to be from 2018. That would be the wrong horse to bet on. IÄ'll check the other ones. Eclipse is of course an option, but the functions that I mentioned in my first post must be available, and there were some IDEs which I checked where I didn't find those options. Except for eclipse which I didn't really take into consideration I don't know the others, so I'll give them a try.